# How to get a field collection field to correctly render with hook_node_presave?

Tags: entities

I have a field collection field that I put one field into, and I am writing a custom module to fill that field. I populated the field myself once via the UI to make sure it would display correctly, and it did.
Then @Aaron showed me [this site](http://audiblecode.com/blog/programmatically-create-and-update-field-collection-item-node-entity-api) in another question that explained a way to do it. I used that code, but when I looked at the array structure it wasn't the same as the array structure created when I populated the fields via the ui.

Here is the code I have:

```
function alternative_titles_title_node_presave($node) {
  if($node->type == "disease_topic") {
    if(!empty($node->field_alternative_titles)) {
      $field_collection_value = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_alternative_titles'));

// Attach to the node
      $field_collection_value->setHostEntity('node', $node);

      $field_collection_value->field_alternative_titles_title[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['title'] = $node->title;
      $field_collection_value->field_alternative_titles_title[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['url'] = $node->path['alias'];

// Save field-collection item.

      dpm($node);
    }

  }
}
```

Here are two images I took. The top one is the ui created array structure and the bottom one is the array structure created by my above code.

UI POPULATED ARRAY STRUCTURE
[image: UI populated]

MY CUSTOM CODE POPULATED ARRAY STRUCTURE
[image: My code Populated]